# send sms from node based on time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cron

I have a scenario where if time of interview is 15 mins from system date then i need to send sms to a particular person .
For this i am using schedular(cron) where it runs for every 15 mins and checks if time of interview(combinedDate in collections) is about 15 mins then it sends sms.

js:

```
var Profiles = require('./profiles.model');
var cron = require('cron');
var cronJob = cron.job("* */15 * * * *", function() {
    var date = new Date();
    Profiles.find({
        combinedDate: Date.parse(Date.parse(date)+60000)
    },function(err, profiless) {

    console.log(profiless);
            console.info('cron job completed');
    });
});
cronJob.start();
```

For now i am just printing message "cron job completed" in console instead of sms.

but here `console.log(profiless);` this statement giving me empty array.

schema:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var ProfilesSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        uniqueId: String,
        combinedDate: Date,
        filepath: String,
        filename: String
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profiles', ProfilesSchema);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your date . You want to check whether the interview time 15 min away from the current time right?

So why don't use something like this?

```
var Profiles = require('./profiles.model');
var cron = require('cron');
var cronJob = cron.job("* */15 * * * *", function() {
var date = new Date();
Profiles.find({
    combinedDate: date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+15)
},function(err, profiless) {

console.log(profiless);
        console.info('cron job completed');
});
});
cronJob.start();
```

Comment: One suggestion from my side. It would be nice to use [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) package for date related manipulation. In moment you can do
`moment().add(15, 'm');`
to get current date time plus 15 minutes.

Comment: my date format is "combinedDate": "Wed Aug 16 2016 11:47:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", Do this effect the calculation?

Comment: I think there will not such issues